# How to append data to label

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, label

I've been following the Stanford iOS development videos on iTunes U,
however I am stuck on a problem!

I am building a calculator and one of the tasks is to send the operations made etc to a label that basically keeps a record of all the numbers and operations pressed.

In my program this should happen every time a button is clicked (which I have done).

However I cannot for some reason send the data to a label in another view controller.

This is what I used to test if it would work in the same view, and it does.

```
self.memoryDisplay.text = [self.memoryDisplay.text stringWithAppendingString:digit];
```

so I thought ill import the second view controller, declare a property label in the second view, synthesize in the main view and send it by using.

```
self.secondview.memoryDisplay.text = [self.memoryDisplay.text stringWithAppendingString:digit];
```

However this does not work, anyone know of a simple way of doing it?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Maybe add a little more context of where these lines of code reside.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand . But why are you trying to update a view directly from a view controller that is not the owner? That's convoluted. Depending on your needs there are other ways to share data across views- simplest is to define a singleton for global data.

Comment: It's because every time a user clicks a button, I want to display what the user clicked in a label on a different screen. basically a record of what the user typed and I have methods in my main view which checks for button presses and updates the label on the main view with what ever the user types in (like a real calculator) I thought the easiest way to do it is to use the same technique

Comment: Why don't you just have all the views (UILabel, UIButton etc) in a single screen managed by a single view controller? I would expect a calculator to have one screen where I enter the commands and see the results. If you are looking for a record of commands, just store it in some data structure (files for instance) that is then accessible from the other view when it gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When we need to send updates to other views/view controllers we use Notifications via NSNitificationCenter.

In the view that has the info that another view needs we do something like this:

```
       // Setup Dictionary to contain values we want to pass.
       NSMutableDictionary *theUserInfo = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1] autorelease];
       // Add our Objects to the Dictionary with a Key to get them out
        [theUserInfo setObject:self forKey:@"ElementWithGesture"];

        NSValue * pointAsObject = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:translation];
        [theUserInfo setValue:pointAsObject forKey:@"PanTranslation"];
        [theUserInfo setObject:gestureRecognizer forKey:@"TheGestureRecognizer"];

            // Post the Group Pan Notification.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNCSEGroupPanGesture
                                                            object:nil 
                                                          userInfo:theUserInfo];
```

Then in the view that needs the Information we add code to tell the Notification Center that we are interested in a specific Notification:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(groupHandlePanGesture:)  // routine that will handle notification
                                                 name:kNCSEGroupPanGesture 
                                               object:nil];
```

Then you need the method that actually handles the posted notification:

```
-(void) groupHandlePanGesture:(NSNotification*)notification{

       // unpack our objects from the dictionary
IoUIScreenElement *element = (IoUIScreenElement *)  [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"ElementWithGesture"];  

if ([self canPan] && ![self elementLocked]) {
       // unpack our pointVlue
    NSValue *pointValue = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"PanTranslation"]; 
    CGPoint translation = [pointValue CGPointValue];

    if (IOFNOTEQUAL(self, element)  & [self isSelected]){
        CGFloat xPosition = self.frame.origin.x + translation.x;
        CGFloat yPosition = self.frame.origin.y + translation.y;

        [self setOrigin:CGPointMake(xPosition, yPosition)];
    }
}
}
```

Then when done listening for notifications, you want to remove your observer. Depending on your views, this is most often done in the delloc.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:kNCSEGroupPanGesture
                                                  object:nil];
```